# How to assign a value from a table to another table in database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my database I have two tables. In table A, I use Update to makes increment exp: 
update number set lastnumber = lastnumber + 1 once got new rerods entered.

How to assign the value from table A to table B?

Answer (score 1):

Join two tables to update, assuming you have a relationship between the two tables... Since you table A is already updated by `SET A.lastnumber = A.lastnumber + 1`, you may use `A.lastnumber` (the new value) to update `B.lastnumber`

```
UPDATE B
SET B.lastnumber = A.lastnumber
FROM TABLE B
JOIN TABLE A
ON A.ID = B.ID
;
```

You may also add `where` clause if you have other more distinct columns and conditions to validate for the join and update...

Comment: @bonCodigo Not, only one table is update and I want take the updated value(table A), assign to table B

Comment: Bella please check on Ic.'s SQLfiddle reference (@Ic. +1 for that). And please do `Set B.lastnumber = A.lastnumber -- since A.lastnumber is already updated with A.lastnumber = A.lastnumber + 1`

Comment: Please clarify if this is not the [expected solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/54e98/1)..

Comment: @bonCodigo I have tried but it seem can't be work. Actually my situation is like that, my table A got 2 fields, one is store number once got new record entered, and one is store alphabet. After that I want to take this number + alphabet assign in my table B (ID field, and it's auto increment), so I can write code to **select** it. Please give some advise. Thanks

Comment: @Bella In that case could you please do `create 2 tables` and `insert into` few rows in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/)? Best way to understand your tables...and data. Also show in your question, how your expected ouput should look like after the update. Very helpful. :)